# Hazelcast Architecture For Multiple Web Apps

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, hazelcast

I have 15 web apps deployed in the same tomcat instance.More or less the same application but tailored for different affiliates.I have 2 production tomcat instances in two seperate machines. Anyway, I 'd like to use hazelcast as a clustered memory grid.What is the best way to do it?

I don't want to go peer to peer and start 15 instances of hazelcast per tomcat.In total it will make 30 instances.Worried about memory overhead and hardship to manage.(Or is this the correct thing to do?)

Other option is,to place the hazelcast jar file under tomcat/lin folder and add a  contextStartListener event to my webapps which will start hazelcast instance on startup.But this means it will check and if not created,create a hazelcast instance.This check will be done for all 15 web apps.This also doesn't look like an optimal solution to me.It might introduce concurrency issues,what if multiple apps start at the same time?

Hence the question again:What is the optimal way to do it?

Comment: You can start hazelcast in a separate process, then start tomcat with the web apps as clients, that said how is it distributed architecture if you're going to do everything in one node?

Comment: Is this a different architecture then using hazelcastinstance in the code and get values in the map?Not familiar with it. As to your question,I have two production nodes,therefore I will have two hazelcast instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hazelcast` is in memory data grid (IMDG), that acts as a distributed storage for datastructures. In a way it's a database. You don't need to start one instance per application, one would suffice. That said, to make it fault tolerant you may cluster multiple nodes together.

For example in your two server setup you can utilize bot the servers to start one instance of Hazelcast and use them in a single cluster. A cluster is the list of the member nodes that are defined in `hazelcast.xml` as below

```
<member-list>
    <member>127.0.0.1</member>
    <member>127.0.0.2</member>
</member-list>
```

If you're running Hazelcast programatically using `Hazelcast.newInstance` this file (hazelcast.xml) would have to be on classpath. Other simpler way is to use `start.bat or start.sh` under `bin` directory of hazelcast download and modify the xml file there.

If you run `Hazelcast.newInstance` or `start.sh` more than once on the same machine it will create as many processes for hazelcast acting as different members clustered together. This is only for experiments and not for production.

To create client use `Hazelcast.newHazelcastClient` by keeping `hazelcast-client.xml` on class path. This xml file will need the member addresses as configured for the servers in the `hazelcast.xml`.

```
<cluster-members>
    <address>127.0.0.1</address>
    <address>127.0.0.2</address>
</cluster-members>
```

Here's a full client XML file from Hazelcast https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-client/src/main/resources/hazelcast-client-full.xml

To create the client follow steps here

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Hazelcast_Clients/Java_Client/Getting_Started.html

**Note:** Client would be created per application, just like you would create database `Connection` instance per application. Server would be run independently from the applications.

Comment: thanks for the insightful explanation! One question:Should the client be open as long as application is up,or it should be shutdown after each communication with the cluster?

Comment: It can be kept alive as long as the application. It's also thread safe so you can create a singleton for it and share it in all threads. Treat it like you would treat a relational database Connection instance.

Answer (score 2):

The optimal way would be to have a standalone (separate) Hazelcast cluster for storing and your applications (webapps) use Hazelcast clients to proxy to the cluster.